# sort data in excel into other cells

Tags: excel

I have an array formula in Excel that returns unsorted values. I want to put the sorted values somewhere else on the sheet and for these values to update and re-sort themselve whenever the source values in the array cells change.

I have no idea how to do this! I suspect it could be done with a macro but I'd rather not do that if I can avoid it.

--- Alistair.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formula as described here:

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/10/11/dynamic-text-sorting/

Comment: Nice, that seems to work for numbers too, even though the link says it doesn't. We are getting a load of NA's though which could be due to multiple identical values. That's a bit of a problem.